# What is the better way to update other state variable which is dependent on another state variable while re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

The scenario is, after mounting the component, in event listener I am setting a state variable and other state variables are being set by making a rest call from backend.

so far what I did is I am using componentWillUpdate and making rest call and setting all the required states.

I tried using componentWillUpdate method to calculate and set other state variables. But its re-rendering multiple times. I guess I am definitely doing something wrong here.

```
export default class Person extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name,
      age: "",
      country: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setDerivedStates();
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    this.setDerivedStates();
  }

  attachListner() {
    document.addEventListner("customEvent", () => {
      this.setState({ name: something });
    });
  }

  setDerivedStates() {
    FetchService.get("url1" + this.state.name).then(response =>
      this.setState({ age: response.age})
    );
    FetchService.get("url2" + this.state.name).then(response =>
      this.setState({ country: response.country })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <p>{this.state.name}</p>
         <p>{this.state.age}</p>
         <p>{this.state.country}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to re-render the component once with all the new state variables. 
Please suggest how should I do it. which lifecycle method and how should I use to set all these states?

Comment: It _should_ re-render every time state is updated.  Why is that a problem?  If you want to cut down on the number of `setStates`, you can use `Promise.all` in your `setDerivedStates()` which would simplify that a bit but in general, this shouldn't be a problem as React is working as intended.

Comment: You are forgetting the `this.` in `setDerivedStates();`

Comment: @larz it's re-rendering again, that I want to cut down.  Somewhere I read we should not do setState in componentWillUpdate method. So I am bit sceptic that i am using wrong lifecycle method. but not sure what else should I use.

Comment: @Vencovsky thanks mate updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap both fetches in [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which will wait for both `Promises` to resolve, if one fails you will have no access to any `Promise/s` that resolves successfully and the operation will throw an `error`.

Add [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to check if the name state has changed, if so refetch.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.name !== this.state.name) {
    this.setDerivedStates();
  } 
}

async setDerivedStates() {
  const url = `url${this.state.name}`;

  try {
    const [age, country] = await Promise.all([
      FetchService.getAge(url),
      FetchService.getCountry(url),
    ]);

    this.setState({ age, country });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('something went wrong', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asaf. I will give it a try. one small ques, will this componentWillUpdate() be not called again if I setState inside it?

Comment: As larz stated, `componentWillUpdate` should be avoided. you can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to handle component updates. the question is, when do you want to refetch the age and the country ? is your `eventListener` listening to input changes ? are you refetching on every key press ? include the listener too

Comment: event is fired on button click. in that event listener, as shown in code snippet I am setting one state and for other state variables i want to make rest call to update it.

Comment: Ok then the current solution should solve it. note that when you change the state from your `eventListener` thats one re-render and then after we are fetching and setting the state another re-render will occur

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all` to batch the two fetches so you only have call `this.setState` once -

```
const [resp1, resp2] = await Promise.all([
        FetchService.get("url1" + this.state.name);
        FetchService.get("url2" + this.state.name);
      ]);

this.setState({ age: resp1.age, country: resp2.country });
```

Also, `componentWillUpdate` is considered [unsafe](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) and will be deprecated in the future.  I would suggest using `componentDidUpdate` instead -

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (prevState.name !== this.state.name) {
        this.setDerviedStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry for the typo. Both are different url. I have updated it.

Comment: componentDidMount is called once after component has mounted. I need to make that rest call after one state changes and component has already mounted so componentDidMount will not be called that time.